# Set d:DesignHeight For All Pages

Tags: wpf, xaml

My WPF project consists of many Pages that all load into the same frame. I currently specify `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth` in the `Page` tag in each individual file.  I would like to just specify it in one place if possible (like a `Style`).

I tried setting it as a Style in my App.xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="PageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
    <Setter Property="d:DesignHeight" Value="942" />
    <Setter Property="d:DesignWidth" Value="1264" />
```

The Pages render correctly in the designer, but the code fails to build:

> Error: Cannot find the Style Property 'DesignHeight' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Page'

How can I set the same `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth` for several pages in one place?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have frame's Width and Height set to the values you need, and let Page instances be without hardcoded value?

Comment: I'm using `d:DesignHeight` not `Height`. "These attributes make it easier to design the composition of the XAML content, so that you have some anticipation of the layout constraints that might exist once that XAML content is used for a control instance or other part of a larger UI page." [XAML namespaces | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't.  The designer properties are not real properties--they are directives that get ignored by the Xaml parser.

In fact, you can only use them when you explicitly tell the parser to ignore them:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

The `mc:Ignorable` directive tells the parser to ignore any lookup failures that occur within the given namespaces.  If you attempt to reference one of the designer properties *without* adding the designer namespace to `mc:Ignorable`, you will get a compile-time error:

> The property 'DesignWidth' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'.

As these are not real properties, you cannot apply them with a `Setter`, nor can you set them programmatically.  Sorry.

---

#### Addendum

I spent some time investigating other options for setting the width and height in design mode.  I tried custom attached properties, subclassing `Page`, and even overriding the default metadata for `Width` and `Height` in design mode.  Invariably, I could get each approach working for almost any control *except* `Window` and `Page`.  I suspect this is because of the way the designer displays windows and pages using special proxy elements.

At this point, I am reasonably confident there is no way to make this work with the VS 2017 Xaml designer.

Comment: I'm guessing then that Bindings and StaticResource require 'real' properties too. Is that correct?

Comment: Does WPF have any type of other project level variable substitution or something like a `#define` in C#? I know these are different mechanisms, but I'm trying to think outside the box a bit for a solution.

Comment: No, but I think I have a solution for you.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Ugh.  I have a solution that lets you set a design-time width and height.  You can set it with a style, but it doesn't actually work for windows or pages, because apparently the WPF designer won't search the application resources for window or page style.  It's probably because the element shown in the designer is a proxy element, not an actual window or page.